# .Net Library to Transform JSON to JSON

Tags: .net, json, transform

Does a .Net library exist for JSON to JSON transformation? I've found one for Java (Jolt) and one for Node.js (json2json), but not a .Net/C# library. I've seen posts suggesting a JSON->XML->XSLT->XML->JSON solution, but that seems hokey at best. Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'd just use Json.NET combined with LINQ... if you could provide an example of what you're trying to achieve, it would be much easier to provide an example of how it might be achieved...

Comment: @JonSkeet, something like https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt, but for C#.